# Using Qt Designer is there a way to set QDockWidgets to hidden as a default?

Tags: user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

Using Qt Designer I have created three QDockWidgets in my main window. I have also created a view menu in the main window menu bar that has three actions that link to each of the three dock widgets. Using signals/slots when these actions are checked or unchecked, the dock widgets are shown or not shown.

However, even if I first set the actions to unchecked and then run the GUI the dock widgets still appear to begin with. I want to be able to start with a blank main window and then the user can select what to open.

My question is, is there a way to set this in Qt Designer or do I need to write it in code into my main window init method?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to hide any widget with Qt Designer, you will have to do it with code.